# What could slow down a iOS App over time besides Memory Leaks?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that adds a lot of UIClasses to many different Views. Views get removed and get added again. **But then after some time working with the app, the app starts to slow down.** Reloading everything, including the Viewcontroller, doesn't help.

The problem is, that i don't know what could slow down the app. **The Memory Usage of the app doesn't go up** and the **CPU usage doesn't go up aswell**. It just seems that the App does everything slower. Views take longer to get added to the view and so on.

Is there anything that i could check what could cause the app to slow down over time? I know that this question is very broad, but maybe someone of you can show me the direction to look at. I`m out of ideas.

Comment: Has to be a leak that you're not seeing.. Retain cycles? Override `dealloc` and print whether or not the controller was deallocated. Do this for each view as well and see which ones weren't deallocated.  Memory fragmentation would also be one reason but I can't see how..

Comment: The other alternative to Time Profiler is to create copy of your app and start ripping things out, e.g., replacing them with low-overhead stubs, one-by-one, re-testing the app at each iteration, and see if you see something that has a more material impact on performance over time than the others.

Comment: Alternately, is there something else in the system that is sucking more CPU over time, thereby depriving your App of run time or contending for some shared resource? Per the other comments, you are going to have to come up with specific work flows that you can time tag and examine how much time they take and decompose that time into smaller operations and see if you can isolate if something in particular is taking longer.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to answer a question like this in the abstract.

I suggest using the Instruments tool and running a time profile. That lets you see where your app is spending most of it's time. You should be able to run the app for a period of time and see the culprit start to take more and more time as you run the app.

Comment: I know that this question is to broad. I`m sorry. But i used every Instrument Tool and with no result. There is happening the exact same stuff as before, just slower.

Comment: Instruments isn't magic. It is a tool that lets you figure out what is going on. You need to study the results and see where the extra delays are coming from.